# How to find variable usage in Android Studio? (like Ctrl + Shift + G in Eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> is used in Eclipse for finding where a variable is used.

How to do the same thing in Android Studio?

Comment: alt-F7 probably. You should take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578776/android-studio-keyboard-shortcut-control

Comment: Great its Working Alt + F7

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Android Studio 
use <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>  and for more check [link!!](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for more details.

Answer (score 6):

**For windows:** ALT + F7

**For Mac:** Option + F7

***NB: Find usage functionality is not only applicable for variable search but also for the usages of Class, Objects, layout and even the drawable images.***

For all the important shortcuts, download [this sheet](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf) and keep copy in your desk.