# Shortcut for copying Ctrl-C not working in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, copy-paste

I am able to copy text from other programs and paste it to Android Studio. I am able to right click and copy selected text. I am able to cut text and paste it using shortcut. But while using shortcut Ctrl + C to copy text I am often unable to copy. This is very annoying problem. Does anyone here knows how to solve it?

Comment: This has happened to me before when I was accessing a computer through RDP. Usually restarting the program or the computer solved it for me.

Comment: I just restarted it and I am able to copy once. After that, old copied text gets pasted when copying and pasting. New text is not copied.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If restarting AS does not resolve the issue you could try Invalidate Caches/Restart option. That sometimes fixes such issues.

----update----

[This](http://tools.android.com/knownissues/ibus) might fix your issue.

Comment: It is under File menu.

Comment: Nope. Now it doesn't copy even once. Text from previous session was pasted while copying and pasting.

Answer (score 9):

Easiest Solution - Reset copy paste in Android Studio by clicking on an empty line and press Ctrl-C to copy nothing (crazy I know but it works). Then recopy your source and paste with Ctrl-V

Comment: Best solution, (happened on Android Studio 2021.3.1 Ubuntu)

Answer (score 7):

Try to uncheck the **Vim Emulator** in **Tools** may solve ur problem!

Answer (score 4):

I used Invalidate Caches/Restart option and worked for me. you could try that.

Comment: for me, this seems to fix the issue for a few minutes, and then the issue returns

Answer (score 1):

Seem to work for me if I: goto Settings > Editor > General > under Limits change "Maximum number of contents to keep in clipboard" to 1.

Then copy *something* from within the Android Studio editor, and then the copy and paste from outside started to work for me.

Comment: i cannot find this option in the settings. did it move?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings -> Keymap -> And then select Eclipse for Keymaps dropdown view. Generally it is set to MAC OS 10 by default

Answer (score 1):

Updating the Android Studio and Invalidate Caches/Restart option doesn't worked for me. But Paste Simple or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> will works when you are trying to paste something from outside.
Try using Copy Reference or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and Paste or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Invalidating cache / restart didn't work for me. Reinstalling didn't work. Clearing the `~/.android` directory didn't work.  No answer I found worked.

What seemed to clear up the situation was disabling the "Android Support" plugin.  Suddenly, cutting and pasting works again.  But then all sorts of debugging features are missing.  So that's not a real solution.

[This is the real solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47185271/756373) that worked for me.  There's some sort of bug upgrading to Studio 3.0 that created an extra `.xml` file under the `menu` folder in `res`.  Removing this file fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

I was setting up Android Studio based off my MAC settings. I found out that I had to change the Keymaps from MAC OSX to Default (Windows)
[Android Studio Keyboard shortcut control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578776/android-studio-keyboard-shortcut-control)

Answer (score 0):

For those migrating from MacOS to Windows, here is an easy fix:

Go to "Settings"

Press on "Keymap" section

Change from "macOS" to "Windows"

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the `Ctrl c` is occupied by other programs(mine is "Oulu Dictionary" program).

Try to check if other programs have a global shortcut key for `Ctrl c`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing issue on on MacOS and you want to use Eclipse shortcuts, then try changing like below,

Android Studio -> Preferences -> search for 'keymap' -> from drop down choose 'Eclipse (macOS)' option

I was not able to copy text from Android Studio using command+c and above configuration change fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

**Open**: File>setting>Plugins. In the installed plugins section uncheck IdeaVim plugin
[image]

Answer (score 0):

copy your text and paste into android studio empty line and copy again , from android studio and paste into emulator , its work !!!