# Android Studio 3.0.1 Cannot copy and paste project files

Tags: git, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, build-error

On Android Studio, I took the full copy of the project folder of an open source code as backup and pasted it on my desktop. After a while, when the project got really messed up, I closed Android Studio and copy-pasted the backup folder inside the project path again. All files were overwritten. However, Android Studio could not build and gave me the error:

`Process 'command 'git'' finished with non-zero exit value 128`

So, what does that mean? What is the way to correct it (without pulling the project from github)?

Comment: It sounds like your blanket paste broke the build, and I'm not sure there is an easy fix.

Comment: So this method of mine should have worked? Because I wonder if this error is related with some kind of a safety mechanism developed by Android Studio or the project uploader to force users to get the code from a reliable source.

Comment: Can you paste them in a new folder and try that instead od reusing the old folder?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I do not know the full details but this issue is related with git log. Git log is where the last state of the project (the last changes in the project) are recorded. So, in brief, when copy-pasted, the state of the new content  does not match with the log entries.

Anyway, it would be nice if someone explained the details.

Comment: yes , in my case , it is related to git , invalidate and restart do solve the problem. may refer this link  https://stackoverflow.com/a/29522711

Comment: Thank you. I hope to tell the result when I try that.