# Android Studio: Ctrl + C is very slow

Tags: android-studio, clipboard, copy-paste

on Windows, every time i press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>, it takes 1-3 seconds to copy the selected text to my clipboard.....ONLY in Android Studio.. other apps are fine.

it is not "not working"; it is just working very slow.

**if you are impacted, please upvote [issue on google bug tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/259026087)**

i already tried answers from this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29522438/2898715), but the issue persists:

1. i don't have IdealVim installed - i can't disable it, since i don't have it installed
2. the setting "Maximum number of contents to keep in clipboard" doesn't exist for me - the setting doesn't exist in my version of Android Studio
3. first copying a blank line doesn't work - copying blank line causes same lag
4. restarting and invalidating caches will fix the issue for a few minutes, but then it just comes back

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this also right now...basically hanging for a few seconds every time. Trying to figure out why...

Comment: thanks for looking into it! but since this is not an answer, please leave this as a comment instead.. for now, i have discovered some workarounds for common use cases (please see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

solution:

1. **vote for [issue on google bug tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/259026087)**
2. wait for fix

workaround for copy + paste:

1. highlight the code you want to copy
2. duplicate the code by pressing: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>
3. use mouse left click to drag-and-drop the code to where you want it

workaround for cut + paste:

1. highlight the code you want to copy
2. use mouse left click to drag-and-drop the code to where you want it

workaround for transferring text to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>:

1. highlight the code/text that you want to search for
2. do the shortcut. i.e., press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>