# Disable shortcut in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I always accidentally do the following keyboard combination <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> which will close all of my open files in Android Studio.

### UPDATED

My apology, I should have been more clearer asking question. The first thing I did is to google it and I did saw the post in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578776/android-studio-keyboard-shortcut-control) but I can't find <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>

See screen shot here:
[image: Screenshot of my keymap]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Keyboard shortcut control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578776/android-studio-keyboard-shortcut-control)

Comment: that is the first thing I did, but there is no SHIFT + ALT + X

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to File -> Settings -> Keymap search for ***Clear Context*** and remove or replace the shortcut

[image: clear context image]

Answer (score 1):

Move to File -> Settings -> Keymap and change Keymaps settings to your keymap,for Example : Visual Studio,so that you can use the short cut keys like in Visual Studio.

[image]

From here,you can enable or disable any shortcut, you want.

Type in Search, Clear Context.

Then on it Right Click, and you will get your choice.

Comment: Hi Vikash, I've updated my question. I don't see ***SHIFT + ALT + X***. Any idea?

Comment: [Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4254283/sam) , Try this one. And Notify me, If you are still in trouble.