# Shortcut to create new line in Android Studio editor

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

What is the **shortcut** to create a new line in Android Studio editor (like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> in Visual Studio Code)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio Keyboard shortcut control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578776/android-studio-keyboard-shortcut-control)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

List of android studio keyboard shortcuts:
[Android keyboard shortcuts](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts)

Answer (score 4):

I believe its <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

If you want to change it ::

> Go to File > Settings > Select Keymap > Select Editor Options > Start
>   a New Line

[image: Image reference]