# How to Change Android Studio Terminal Key Mappings

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ide

I want to change Android Studio Terminal's Key Mappings to match my macOS Key Mappings

On my macOS Key Mappings i am using preset: Natural Text Editing

Android Studio does not allow me to change Key Mappings of its embedded terminal

Comment: May it will help you 
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/25419316/7344185.

Answer (score -1):

You can select the preset control for Mac OS by going to below path

`File -> Settings -> from left pane select Keymap`

By default you can change settings from dropdown and select Mac OS option from here.

[image]

Also, If you want to edit particular entry you can do that by double clicking any item and `Edit Shorcuts` dialog should appear.

Comment: This settings for Keymap of Android Studio IDE.
My question is how to change "configure" the embedded terminal's Keymap.