# Shortcut keys are updated on Android Studio 3.5

Tags: android, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

On Android Studio 3.5 shortcut keys are updated and different from the previous one, how can i move these keys to previous version ?

I don't understand why they have updated the shortcut keys on Android Studio 3.5 !

Comment: Have you imported the previous version settings after upgrading the studio?

Comment: i don't remember that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578776/android-studio-keyboard-shortcut-control use this