# How to change android studio keyboard shortcut

Tags: flutter, android-studio, shortcut

I don't want the shortcut to work when shift is pressed twice in android studio.

Because When entering uppercase letters, It is very inconvenient.

I tried to change it in the change window, Shift twice-press shortcut still works.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio Keyboard shortcut control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578776/android-studio-keyboard-shortcut-control)

Answer (score 0):

I found this in the documentation of Android Studio.
[https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts#:~:text=To%20open%20the%20keymap%20settings,to%20switch%20between%20preset%20keymaps.](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts#:%7E:text=To%20open%20the%20keymap%20settings,to%20switch%20between%20preset%20keymaps.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But even if you do it that way, the shortcut key for pressing shift twice is executed.